# Create Intersect of HashSet and remove Items from class structure with extracted ID's

Tags: c#, list, intersection, hashset

lets assume I have the following classes:

```
public class ServiceStatistics
{
    public string LocalId { get; set; }
    public string OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public List<StatisticElements> Elements { get; } = new List<StatisticElements>();
}

public class StatisticElements
{
    public string StatisticId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
}
```

I retrieve such ServiceStatistics by a soap service and I use serialization/deserialization.

Each ServiceStatistics contains a set of StatisticElements. I also have a static list of StatisticElements-ID's which are relevant for calculation. All other incoming StatisticElements-ID's can be dropped. I need to do this on my side
because the SOAP Service does not support selecting specific StatisticElements-ID's

So I have generated a static Class with a HashSet:

```
public static class RelevantDutyPlans
{
    private static HashSet<int> relevantDutyPlans;

    static RelevantDutyPlans()
    {
        // only a subset of the original ID's
        relevantDutyPlans = new HashSet<int>()
        {
            530,
            1150,
            1095,
        };
    }

    public static HashSet<int> GetRelevantDutyPlans()
    {
        return relevantDutyPlans;
    }

    public static bool Contains(int planId)
    {
        return relevantDutyPlans.Contains(planId);
    }

    // Extracts all DutyPlans which are relevant (HashSet) for validation from
    // the incoming data
    public static List<int> ExtractRelevantDutyPlans(List<int> planIds)
    {
        var relevantPlans = new HashSet<int>(planIds);

        relevantPlans.IntersectWith(relevantDutyPlans);

        return relevantDutyPlans.ToList();
    }
}
```

So my thought was, to create an Intersect like this:

```
List<ServiceStatistics> statistics = SoapService.GetStatistics(Now);

List<int> incomingIds = new List<int>();

foreach(var item in statistics)
{
    foreach(var element in item.Statistic)
    {
        incomingIds.Add(int.Parse(element.StatisticId));
    }
}

List<int> extract = RelevantDutyPlans.ExtractRelevantDutyPlans(incomingIds);
```

So now I have a List of ID's which are relevant for further processing. What I want to achieve is to remove all class elements "StatisticElements" with "StatisticId" not contained in the the extract list generated above.

Any ideas?

Any help is very appreciated

Comment: Your `Extract` returns the wrong variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a little bit different approach.  Simply remove irrelevant plans right away!

```
List<ServiceStatistics> statistics = SoapService.GetStatistics(Now);

foreach(var item in statistics)
{
   item.Elements.RemoveAll(x => !RelevantDutyPlans.Contains(int.Parse(x.StatisticId)));
}
```

Now you are only left with the relevant once.

Comment: This is a very nice approach, thx alot :) Will check if it fits in the workflow and give feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope you can use **selectMany** to flatten the collection and proceed the filter.

```
var filteredItems =  statistics.SelectMany(s => s.Elements)
                  .Where(s => extract.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(s.StatisticId)))
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use LINQ to create a new `List<>` if you need to keep the original `statistcs` intact - e.g. if you might run multiple plans against it.

```
var relevantStatistics = statistics.Select(s => new {
                                                LocalId = s.LocalId,
                                                OrganizationId = s.OrganizationId,
                                                Elements = s.Elements.Where(e => !RelevantDutyPlans.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(e.StatisticId))).ToList()
                                           });
```

Since `ServiceStatistics` doesn't provide for construction, I return an anonymous object instead, but you could create an appropriate DTO class.